# Lifecycle for controlled textinputs

Tags: forms, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I was wondering if the mobx cycle is triggered on observable change only in stores outside of react components in HOClass operation
because there is a top level Provider to mobx stores which is triggering a react component re-render.

```
  ReactDOM.render(<Provider { ...stores } >
              <Routes />
              </Provider>,
```

But does that mean I can't add observables directly to react components?
if so that is a bit unfortunate.

```
@observer
export default class Profile extends React.Component {
  @observable name;
  componentWillMount() {
    this.name = this.props.name;
  }
  txtChange = (e) => {
    this.name = e.target.value;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={this.txtChange} value={this.name}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

for some reason on my app I cannot update the observable name. On some apps using mobx however I can. Why am I unable to change the value of this and trigger a react state update if the observable is attached to the React.Component itself?

Here I have forms updating in controlled observable fashion but when Provider 'ing my router on my current project under this setup no react rerender is triggered.

https://codepen.io/cheapsteak/pen/wzdvzQ

Help anyone?

Answer (score 0):

There (was) a typo: the function is called `txtChange` but the component references `this.txthange` instead. Either way, here's a fixed working example: https://codepen.io/justnobody/pen/RxJmmY?editors=1010

Comment: in codepen it works, in my local project howevertextinput does not update. I will provide a github repo in a few minutes.